# Visual Studio Remote Debugger cannot connect to server - WebDAV MiniRedir reports PROPFIND not implemented

Tags: webdav

Symptoms: 
You have installed and run the Visual Studio Remote Debugger on your SharePoint server. 
You can debug the IIS worker process in the terminal session on the server. 
You cannot connect to the Remote Debugger from your development workstation.
Network response packets show "WebDAV MiniRedir ... PROPFIND not implemented" messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the "Server" service using services.msc on the Server will help you connect to the Remote Debugger.